Disable Interactive Dismissal of Navigation Transitions in SwiftUI
I am using the new navigationTransitionStyle(.zoom(id, namespace)) to zoom from a view preview to a detail view in my swiftUI app.
My issue is that I have a snapping scrollView in the detail view, that when users try to swipe to minimize, accidentally dismisses the entire detailView. I would like, in effect, to disable this 'pull down to dismiss' behavior of the new transition style.
Attempted Solutions

I noticed that applying a .highPriorityGesture( DragGesture() ) prevents the interaction, however, applying that onto my detailView disables the primary vertical scrollView, which is not good. I have tried to programmatically apply the gesture, but am not able to get a solution working
.interactiveDismissDisabled(true) does not work for .navigationTransitionStyle
.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true) does not disable the pull down dismiss behavior for the new zoom transition as it does for the swipe dismiss behavior in the old slide navigation transition. See this post
Setting .dragGesture(minimumDistance: 15) as suggested on this post correctly enables the ScrollView, but does not block out the swipe Dismiss behavior
Using .highPriorityGesture( LongPressGesture(minDuration: 0) ) has the same effect as the drag gesture, in that it disables both the swipe dismiss behavior and the scrollView

I am beginning to think there is no way to disable this gesture, but if anybody knows a way, or a workaround that would let me use my scrollView with this new transition, I would be very happy
Update

I tried using a UIScrollView instead of a swiftUI ScrollView in the hopes that the .highPriorityGesture wouldn't block it, but it overwrites the scroll gestures

